# Flink with Kafka as a source

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to read the data from kafka topic, in Flink streaming. I am trying to run the following example code which is there as an example on page APACHE Flink 1.1.3 Documentation: Apache kafka connector,

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.DeserializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SerializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;

public class stock_streaming_kafka {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env=StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String> myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>("nsestocks4k", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties);

    DataStream<String> stream = env
        .addSource(myConsumer)
        .print();
}
```

}

I have following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The type org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
The method addSource(SourceFunction<OUT>) in the type StreamExecutionEnvironment is not applicable for the arguments (FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String>)

at stock_streaming_kafka.main(stock_streaming_kafka.java:25)
```

Can you please guide me to fix this? Is there any dependency issue with Kafka connector. 
My versions are:

1. Flink 1.1.3
2. Kafka 2.10
3. flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11-1.0.0.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below versions. It will work with your Kafka version.

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

I see a Compilation issue in the code.

Change this:

```
DataStream<String> stream = env
        .addSource(myConsumer)
        .print();
```

to:

```
DataStream<String> stream = env
        .addSource(myConsumer);
stream.print();
```

If it still doesn't work for you then please let me know and I will share the working code.

Answer (score 0):

The versions of Flink and the Flink connector must match.
Update the `flink-connector` dependency to 1.1.3.

Comment: Thanx Fabian. I have changed the jar version to flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11-1.1.3.jar. But I got the error as   _The type org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedDeserializationSchema cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files_

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer is not accepted yet, here is a [complete Maven code example](https://github.com/deshpandetanmay/mastering-flink/tree/master/chapter02/flink-streaming) to read data from Kafka using Flink.

You may need to tweak the [pom.xml](https://github.com/deshpandetanmay/mastering-flink/blob/master/chapter02/flink-streaming/pom.xml) to match your setup of Kafka and Scala versions.

Hope this helps.